# HighCharts specifying min, max and tickInterval not giving expected results

Tags: highcharts

I have set up a sample at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwatling/Y25kv/12/) of 2 charts which I think should have identical ticks on the yAxis. The first uses

```
yAxis: [{
    tickInterval: 94000,
    min: 628000,
    max: 1004000
}]
```

and the second (desired result) uses

```
yAxis: [{
    tickPositions: [628000, 722000, 816000, 910000, 1004000]
}]
```

Am I doing something wrong in the first example, or should this be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Logic in Highcharts is a little different from 'set min, interval and will work'. It rounds values to make more readable etc. In your example it is not so obvious actually.

If you don't want use build-in logic for setting ticks, write your own using tickPositioner. For example:

```
    tickInterval: 94000,
        tickPositioner: function(min,max){
            var act = min,
                ticks = [];
            console.log(this);
            while(act <= max){
                ticks.push(act);
                act+= this.tickInterval;
            }
              return ticks;  
        },
        min: 628000,
        max: 1004000
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y25kv/15/).

Comment: Nice example of tickPositioner function!